# see more info from git pull via shell_exec()

Tags: php, git, shell

When I use PuTTY to connect to my server, and I manually type in all the git commands in the console, `git pull` will display something like this:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 1), reused 2 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
```

However, when I run the same commands via PHP's `shell_exec()` I get nothing.

It performs all the requested operations, but doesn't show me any information in the process. Not even success or failure at the end. It has no output.

Where did all this information come from that the PuTTY console is showing, but PHP won't output? How can I get access to this information via PHP?

Comment: Could you show us the actual PHP code? Interacting with shell in PHP isn't always straightforward.

Comment: @ErwinMoller as I said, my code performs all the requested operations. Only it doesn't give me useful/interesting output in the process while I wait.

Comment: I believe you when you say the commands ran successfully. It is just that interacting with a program Unix style isn't always straightforward. phd gave you some background hereunder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix command line programs distinguish interactive and non-interactive usage by asking if standard streams (stdin/stdout/stderr) are connected to a terminal. PuTTY is a terminal so `git pull` runs in the interactive mode. `git pull` writes the progress to stderr.

Under web (CGI, PHP, etc) stderr is redirected to httpd server logs so `git pull` runs in non-interactive mode. You can force `git pull` to display progress using option [`--progress`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---progress) but you also have to redirect stderr to stdout so that you can catch the output.

Comment: Thank you, this was the correct answer. `--progress` and redirecting `stderr`. I have posted below the exact PHP implementation

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I'm posting the actual code I wrote to solve this:

`shell_exec( 'git pull --progress origin master 2>/home/user/domain.com/stderr.txt' );`

This will write all the "progress" style output messages into a file called stderr.txt which can then be dynamically read from a separate process.